# R: Failure to see source code of Psych package

Tags: r, package, rstudio

Source code of some packages can be accessed by loading package, putting cursor on the package name and pressing F2. For example:

```
 library(ltm)
```

Yields the following (only first 5 lines of source code are shown below):

```
 function (formula, constraint = NULL, IRT.param, start.val = NULL,
 na.action = NULL, control = list())
 {     
 cl <- match.call() 
 tm <- terms(formula)
```

I am trying to view source code of package called psych

```
 library(psych)
```

But all I see is the following

```
1 function () 
2 {
3 }
```

Any idea why source code is not shown and how to find it? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works for functions not entire packages. It happens to work for ltm because the package also has a function called ltm. Choose the specific function you want to view source code of.

```r
diagram

function (fit, ...) 
{
    fn <- NULL
    if (length(class(fit)) == 1) {
        if (class(fit) == "lavaan") 
            fn <- "lavaan"
    }
    if (length(class(fit)) > 1) {
        fn <- class(fit)[2]
    }
    switch(fn, fa = {
        fa.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, principal = {
        fa.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, iclust = {
        iclust.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, omega = {
        omega.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, lavaan = {
        lavaan.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, bassAck = {
        bassAckward.diagram(fit, ...)
    }, extend = {
        extension.diagram(fit, ...)
    })
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000286e21e8>
<environment: namespace:psych>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped to clarify the situation!